# Removing the border around the content in Protostar

Tags: templates, css, styling, protostar

The Protostar template has a border around all the content and modules, except for the footer module. How do I get rid of this border?

[image: border in protostar]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file called `user.css` in the following directory:

> templates/protostar/css

and add the folowing code:

```
.body .container,
.well {
    border: none;
}
```